# How to find param of child route in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

Lets say i have 2 routes like:

```
/users  - shows list of users
  -/:id - shows detail of selected user
```

Given a url for the above route, the `/users` route needs to know the `/:id` param so it can show that users as 'selected' in its list.

How do i then get the `/:id` in the `/users` route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [paramsFor](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_paramsFor), in `users route` you do `this.paramsFor('route-name')` to get parameters of given route